# Wordpress not center align images when published

Tags: css, wordpress

I have very limited knowledge of CSS. I have a site published on wordpress and I can not get any images to center align. I have tried adding additional CSS as mentioned in a few of my troubleshooting search responses, to no avail.'

I have a TERSO custom child theme I am using. I am thinking perhaps there is something in the theme that is preventing the image CSS from applying? This is on the homepage of the website festiVOL.com

Below is the image CSS - I am not sure what else I should include to assist with figuring this out. Thanks to anyone that can help me out!!

- amy

```
<!-- wp:image {"align":"center","id":1702,"sizeSlug":"large","linkDestination":"media","className":".aligncenter { margin-left: auto; margin-right: display: block; }"} -->
<div class="wp-block-image .aligncenter { margin-left: auto; margin-right: display: block; }"><figure class="aligncenter size-large"><a href="https://festivol.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/festiVOL-OneSheet-3Cheers-Grahic-Diamond-1.png"><img src="https://festivol.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/festiVOL-OneSheet-3Cheers-Grahic-Diamond-1.png" alt="" class="wp-image-1702"/></a></figure></div>
<!-- /wp:image -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the attached image. Hope that's the one you are trying to align to the centre.

[image]

Two options.
a) Add inline style using style="" attribute

```
<img style="text-align: center" />
```

b) Using a class which you have applied. Add the .aligncenter class to your style sheet and apply the class to the div as follows.

```
<div class="wp-block-image aligncenter">
.aligncenter { text-align: center; }
```

Comment: yes that is the image I am trying to center - thank you!